# HTML mail remove space under image in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have a problem with images in my mail. Template is built on tables. Here is the code (part).

```
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 600px; display: block; border: none; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="142" valign="top"><a href="http://katarina.edu.pl/"><img border="0" src="http://poligon.netivo.pl/new_wordpress/images/katarina_banner_1.png" alt="Zarezerwuj kurs ze zniżką 100 zł do 12.09.15"/></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="130" valign="top"><a href="http://katarina.edu.pl/"><img border="0" src="http://poligon.netivo.pl/new_wordpress/images/katarina_banner_2.png" alt="31.08 rusza ostatni kurs wakacyjny - 3 tygodnie i mówisz. Zapraszamy"/></a></td></tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </table>
```

When I send this email via Outlook 2010 under the first image there is a 2px gap, which I want to remove. I tried many ways (surround with div, with specified height), adding align left to image to table cell.

Only one answer seems to work, adding ***display:block*** to image, and it looks great in Outlook. When I send the email and look at it through gmail and hotmail the gap is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `display:block` directly on the element.

```html
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 600px; display: block; border: none; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="142" valign="top"><a href="http://katarina.edu.pl/"><img border="0" style="display:block" src="http://poligon.netivo.pl/new_wordpress/images/katarina_banner_1.png" alt="Zarezerwuj kurs ze zniżką 100 zł do 12.09.15"/></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" height="130" valign="top"><a href="http://katarina.edu.pl/"><img style="display:block" border="0" src="http://poligon.netivo.pl/new_wordpress/images/katarina_banner_2.png" alt="31.08 rusza ostatni kurs wakacyjny - 3 tygodnie i mówisz. Zapraszamy"/></a></td></tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
</table>
```

Gmail not allowing `<style>` in head or body

[image: From https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/]

Comment: First time i did what u said(inline style). But it works only in Outlook.

Comment: Ok.. Try sending me a test-mail 
privat@thomasbolander.dk